# How to keep track of the number of emits in flowable?

Tags: android, rx-java, rx-java2

Let's say I have a  flowable, that some view is subscribed to and it's listening to the changes. I would like to add a custom method based on only the first emit of the flowable, but also keeping the other methods that listen to the changes. What is the best way to approach it? 
The naive approach I have is to duplicate the flowable and convert it to Single or Completable to get the results, but it seems redundant.

Thank you.

Comment: Title does not really match description.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.take(1)`. BTW also make sure that flowable is shared (otherwise some observers will miss events).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `share` operator for that. `Share` operator makes a Connectable Observable. And then Connectable Observable publishes items each subscribes.

```
val o = Flowable.fromArray(1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
    .map {
        println("heavy operation")
        it + it
    }
    .share() // publish the changes
    .subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()) // for testing. change what you want

o.take(1).subscribe { println("Special work: $it") } // take one

o.subscribe { println("Normal work: $it") }
```

Result

```
heavy operation
Special work: 2
Normal work: 2
heavy operation
Normal work: 4
heavy operation
Normal work: 6
heavy operation
Normal work: 8
heavy operation
Normal work: 10
```